# user authentication in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

I need to implement a login feature for the web application that I am building on eclipse using Java EE and Tomcat, [JDBCRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) has been suggested for this purpose, but I don't understand why I can't simply get the login and password and check against the database for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but then you are rebuilding the same functionality that is already built into JDBCRealm, you will also have user roles built into the system. Up front it will probably be easier to do your own login and password check but in the long run JDBCRealm should be more maintainable.

Comment: As you are making assertions about pages instead of code for pages it should be easier to expand and add page types and all that. I am saying should be easier because I personally haven't done both ways in a similar enough situation to really know.